# How to make a PUT call with a GET call as the promise

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, pdfsharp

I have a modal with a form that has 3 options, Save, Update, and Email(PdfSharp). I need to be able to change something in the form and have that change show up it the Pdf. Right now I need to make a Update, then reopen the modal before the change can be seen in the Pdf. How can I make to calls at the same time? I tried to use the Email function as the Update promise but it is not working.

```
<input ng-click="updateJob(currentItem)" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" value="Email"/>
```

Angular Controller

```
//Update Job 
$scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    jobFactory
        .updateJob(job)
        .success(successCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);

    console.log(job);
};

$scope.job = [];
var successCallback = function (job, status, headers, config) {
    var id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
};

var errorCallback = function (job, status, headers, config) {
    notificationFactory.error(job.ExceptionMessage); 
};
```

Email Function

```
$scope.EmailPdf = function () {
    var id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

Comment: Non of my business but are you sure that you want to reload the page before the successCallback?

Comment: yes, I need to remove that from this post. thanks